# Como exibir a imagem do BD no php?

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um site para vendas (coisa pessoal, apenas treinando) e meu problema acontece com a exibição da imagem carregada do BD. O navegador identifica que tem uma imagem ali, porém ele não mostra a mesma.

**Envio a imagem por `$_FILES` no HTML**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8/">
    </head>
    <body>
          <form name="enviaImg" action="salvaImg.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="imagem" value=""/>
                <p>Categoria: <input type="text" name="eCategProd"/></p>
                <p>Descricao: <input type="text" name="eDescricao"/></p>
                <p>Preco: <input type="text" name="ePreco"/></p>
                <input type="submit" name="envia" value="Salvar"/>
          </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**salvo a imagem em PHP com o `$_FILES`:**

```
    <?php
          $nomeProd = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
          $temp = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"];
          $categProd = $_POST["eCategProd"];
          $precoProd = $_POST["ePreco"];
          $descProd = $_POST["eDescricao"];

          $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ecomoveis');
          $insere = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tb_produto (prod_Nome, prod_Descricao, prod_Categoria, prod_Url, prod_Preco) VALUES ('{$nomeProd}', '{$descProd}', '{$categProd}', '{$temp}', '{$precoProd}')") or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

          move_uploaded_file($temp, "../EcoMoveis/Moveis/".$nomeProd);

          header("location: enviar.php");
      ?>
```

**Leio e organizo em um vetor e exibo em outra pagina PHP:**

```
     <?php 
         $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ecomoveis');
         $consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tb_produto WHERE prod_Categoria = 'Cadeira'");

         while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
         {
            $produto[] = $linha;
         }
     ?>
```

**E por fim exibo em um campo qualquer dentro de `<body>`**

```
   <html>
      <body>
         <div class="produto-imagem">
              <?php 
                 include("../PHP/Cadastro de Produtos/pegaImg.php");
                 foreach($produto as $prod)
                 {
              ?>
              <img src="<?php echo "../EcoMoveis/Moveis/".$prod["prod_Nome"] ?>"/>
              <?php 
                 }
              ?>
        </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

No caso existem 2 imagens com a categoria "Cadeira", então ele coloca 2 quadrados (iguais aos que aparece quando não reconhece a imagem) mas nada da imagem aparecer

Comment: Na verdade vc não está salvando a imagem no BD, apenas o nome dela.

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo, entao eu consegui fazer ela aparecer na mesma pagina ("enviaImg.php"), mas eu preciso que apareca em uma outra pagina .php  e é ai que a coisa enrosca, pq ele identifica que tem uma imagem ali, ele so nao aparece a imagem

Comment: @Sam, poderia me mostrar uma forma de salvar a imagem no BD?

Comment: Se as imagens tem o mesmo caminho, o que vc vai fazer é salvar o nome, por exemplo: `imagem1.jpg`

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta  a imagem está salva em uma pasta no servidor então para aparecer em qualquer página você tem que colocar no atributo `src` da imagem o endereço relativo da imagem

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo entao, consegui resolver o problema, era porque o arquivo que pega a imagem no bd e o arquivo que mostra a imagem estava em pastas diferentes. Obrigado pela atencao de todos, desculpa qualquer coisa o/

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: nao tem como eu marcar "resposta aceita" em comentario

Comment: Ops, eu sei, foi só pra você saber que existe essa de marcar resposta como aceita.

Comment: Faltou definir a extensão do arquivo. Dica: Sempre que salvar caminhos com nomes de arquivos no banco de dados, salve o nome do arquivo com a extensão.